# Handle android billing response when successful popup appear

Tags: android

Here is my sample code to handle billing response:

```
private PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Purchase Updated Listener");
      Log.d(TAG, "responseCode: " + responseCode);

      if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
        Purchase purchase = purchases.get(0);
        Log.d(TAG, "purchase success, responseCode: " + responseCode);
        //do something

      } else {
        if (result != null) {
          Log.d(TAG, "purchase error, responseCode: " + responseCode);
          //do something

        }
      }
    }
};

mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mContext).setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener).build();
```

I succeeded to buy an item, but it has an problem on the payment flow:

step1: When i complete my purchase, the payment successfull popup appear

[image]

step2: close the popup then onPurchasesUpdated is called and we can handle the response code.

The problem is how can i handle response code (or detect payment successfull) when the popup is appear. At this time the onPurchasesUpdated is only called after the popup closed

Comment: you can only detect that after the dialog disappears. Can you tell me your use case of why you want to detect it before?

Comment: I want to update the database on my server after user buy this item but if the app is killed or device lost the connection before the payment successful dialog disappears, i can't update my server and user wallet still charged

Comment: in that case you can check with the payment ID from which you have initialised this payment when you come back whether the payment for this ID was a success 
or not!. You only need to keep track of the paymentIds

Comment: Sorry for missing information, my in-app products which is created on play console is just the item type, the item list is stored in my server. After user by an item, i need to update the item state on the server and consume the responding in-app product (item type).

Comment: And my app allow multiple user, so i must store each user's item on my server